# What do BU and USR in compiler lingo mean?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

On my journey learning about llvm and clang, I came across the abbreviations `BU` and `USR`. I have not been able to find out what they mean.

I am assuming `BU` is some kind of *unit* - just like `TU` is a *translation unit*.
I saw it being used [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56698#issue-1316326123) talking about "[...] several `BU`s are compacted inside a larger `TU` [...]".

Also I was able to find, that apparently `USR`s can be *[generated](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/USRGeneration_8cpp_source.html)* from `AST`s.

- What do these abbreviations stand for and what do they mean?
- Are these abbreviations common compiler lingo or merely used by llvm?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [the clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__XREF.html#ga51679cb755bbd94cc5e9476c685f2df3):

> A Unified Symbol Resolution (USR) is a string that identifies a particular entity (function, class, variable, etc.) within a program. USRs can be compared across translation units to determine, e.g., when references in one translation refer to an entity defined in another translation unit.

Also from the [the clang-tags User Manual](https://ffevotte.github.io/clang-tags/#sec-1-3):

> A symbol can not be identified by its spelling only: context information is needed to disambiguate uses of the same spelling in different scopes. In order to uniquely identify a symbol across all translation units in a project, clang defines Unified Symbol Resolutions.

As for `BU`, this might refer to the [Boost.Units library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_units.html).

Comment: Thank you - that clears things up regarding USR! I added a link to where I saw `BU` begin used.